# Intel XDK demo URL/Iframe App cannot save/download file

Tags: html, cordova, intel-xdk

I use the Intel XDK demo Iframe/URL App to open a website. But I can not download files into phone local storage. Can anyone help why it happened?

I use this code https://github.com/gomobile/sample-url-app/tree/master/www/ in intel xdk cordova build. I have a problem when I download/save file from website into my android storage. The link download is working in browser but not in my app. Give me a solution that I understand because I'm a just beginner.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail of what you're trying to do?  Some code would help as well.  You might try inappbrowser instead of iframe.

Comment: I use this code [https://github.com/gomobile/sample-url-app/tree/master/www](https://github.com/gomobile/sample-url-app/tree/master/www) in intel xdk cordova build. I have a problem when I download/save file from website into my android storage. The link download is working in browser but not in my app. Give me a solution that I understand because I'm a just beginner.

Comment: How are you trying to download the file exactly?

Comment: I embed an external website into an iframe that where the website has a file to download. I downloaded like in general. This is my [sample app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f2yopzbi5l7apu/IframeSample.android.20141203142114.apk?dl=0)